# lua.vm.js object/array to table

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lua

I am using lua.vm.js to give users of my node application the ability to add features in realtime. For that I have some JS Classes that I want to give them in lua.

Now I have the problem, that some of my functions should return arrays or objects.
On Lua side it is translated to userdata. In the most cases this will work but not for a array that should be used in a ipairs/pairs function.

I now that "in ipairs" or "in pairs" is existing in lua.vm.js

The question is how can I write a function that returns an array in a way that lua.vm.js is using it as a table.

Some example Code:

on JS side:

```
let luaVM = require("lua.vm.js");
let l = new luaVM.Lua.State();
l._G.set("someExampleFunction", {
    example: function(){
        return [1,2,3,4,5];
    }
});
```

on Lua Side:

```
local shouldBeTable = someExampleFunction.example()

-- this will not work because shouldBeTable is not a table
for key, value in pairs(shouldBeTable) do
    print(value)
end
```

Is there a way how to do that or to write a helper Function like arrayToTable ?

Comment: Is this what `js.ipairs` and `js.pairs` are for? Though it looks like those should Just Work if I'm reading things correctly. Are you sure this doesn't Just Work?

Comment: it is not working because lua.vm.js does not read js arrays/objects as a table. It says it is userdata instead. Thats why i am asking how can i set it to a table.

Comment: You are getting an error when you try it? Did you try `js.pairs` manually? (I could absolutely be wrong but it looks like this should be working I think.)

Comment: okay found a Solution: I execute now a customized Variant of https://github.com/kripken/lua.vm.js/blob/master/src/js.lua before executing die Lua-Code from the User.

Comment: You customized that yourself? What did you change? That sounds like something you should write up as an answer here and possibly submit to lua.vm.js itself.

Comment: In didn't customized lua.vm.js so it is not really a Solution. But in the git repository you have that js.paris as a lua code and you can execute it as lua code before executing the own code... then it is working.... not a nice solution but it works

Comment: I don't understand what you meant but yes, I did mention `js.pairs` in my first comment since it looked like it might be useful here.